# Vagrantfile ruby syntax explanation

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I'm confused with the ruby syntax used to configure Vagrant. Especially with this construct. Is this an assignment, a method call, or something else? Is it pure ruby or vagrant specific dialect?

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

And this one. Is the "ansible" an assignment or an argument, and where |ansible| comes from?

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "provisioners/docker.yml"
end
```

Where I can find more information about those specific expressions?

Comment: Any information you can find in the google. I suggest you read basic about [ruby_methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm) and  [ruby_blocks](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm)

Answer (score 3):

The Vagrantfile is written in standard Ruby syntax.

Here is an example Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # this is an evaluation statement
  # .box is an string attribute
  config.vm.box = "debian/stretch64"

  # this is a method call
  # .synced_folder is a method that takes two positional arguments ('synced_folder', '/vagrant'), 
  # followed by some keyword arguments (disabled: true)
  config.vm.synced_folder 'synced_folder', '/vagrant', disabled: true

  # this is a method call, followed by a "do ... end" block
  # .provider is a method that takes one positional argument (:libvirt)
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |node|
    # these are two evaluation statements
    node.cpus = 4
    node.memory = 4096
  end
end
```

From the official documents,
you can see the variable "string" in "[config.vm.box (string)](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html#config-vm-box)",
but not following the methods [config-vm-provider](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html#config-vm-provider) and [config-vm-synced_folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html#config-vm-synced_folder).

I was also confused about the Vagrantfile syntax, even after reading the offical documents. 
I think it's because Ruby looks very different to me compared to other languages I used before.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), Ruby is a very good language for writing DSL, take a look a this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936146/tutorials-for-writing-dsl-in-ruby)

Although those are DSLs, you can throw vanilla Ruby code outside those blocks, and probably inside as well as long as it gets evaluated.